# How to call hash function in solidity to free a stuck smart contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, transactions, ether

I was selling an altcoin on Etherdelta using a sell order and 3 transactions went through however the ethereum did not show up in my wallet. I contacted support and they say that "your altcoin is stuck in the smart contract" and "you need to call in a hash function for solidity". I have no idea what that means.

Here are the transactions:

```
0x22d6d860c7c2ac7211304a2ef64b092fb860c4b00b87b8092dc3aef2549450f6

0x1dfe2a2a41561c1660f02b92c770d550d3ff70dc73fad15c4dfece867ba8e757

0xd36988c5ac1c1648543f9c653870bd6652c886a39a8b78e66bae097d60b291fa
```

Comment: Make it clear please: Where are you sending from? To where? Provide transaction hashes.

Comment: Cred to Ethereum
Transaction hashes - https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1dfe2a2a41561c1660f02b92c770d550d3ff70dc73fad15c4dfece867ba8e757

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd36988c5ac1c1648543f9c653870bd6652c886a39a8b78e66bae097d60b291fa

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x22d6d860c7c2ac7211304a2ef64b092fb860c4b00b87b8092dc3aef2549450f6